# FullCalendar Json Events not loading through function

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, vb.net, fullcalendar

I am using the fullcalendar control in a vb.net web project. If I hardcode the events: property on the full calendar to a string it loads correctly but I can't get data to load through a POST function.

This is the hardcoded value to use a string from the page

```
events: [<%=eventstring %>]
```

This is the test value I hardcoded in the code behind.

```
eventstring = "{ title: 'Testing - This is a test', start:'2014-02-05T19:10:00-04:00' , end: '2014-02-05T19:10:00-03:00', allDay : false   }"
```

That correctly displays the activity on the calendar. If I try the following I do not get the activity to load on the calendar.

```
events: function (start, end, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "calendar.aspx/LoadCalendarEvents",
        data: '{startDate: "' + $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'M/d/yyyy') + '",' + 'endDate: "' + $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, 'M/d/yyyy') + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

    });
},
```

This is the function in the codebehind. It returns the exact same string.

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function LoadCalendarEvents(ByVal startDate As String, ByVal endDate As String) As String
    Dim eventstring As String = ""

    eventstring = "{ title: 'Testing - This is a test', start:'2014-02-05T19:10:00-04:00' , end: '2014-02-05T19:11:00-03:00', allDay : false   }"

    Return eventstring
End Function
```

I have put a breakpoint in the LoadCalendarEvents function and can see that it is getting called when the date on the calendar changes and is returing the string.

What am I missing? Why does the event not display on the calendar when using the POST function?

Comment: Can you tell us how you solved your problem?

Comment: I have added how I solved the problem as the accepted answer. I tried to remove unnecessary code to simplify the answer a bit. Let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get fullcalendar to load the events successfully by having the webmethod return an array instead of a json string.

This is how I setup the eventsources function in javascript. I removed additional fields from the success function and a couple of other functions to load events from different sources to shorten the answer.

```
eventSources: [
                // Load Standard Events For Employee
                function (start, end, callback) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/calendar.aspx/LoadCalendarEvents",
                        data: '{startDate: "' + $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'M/d/yyyy') + '",' + 'endDate: "' + $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, 'M/d/yyyy') + '  "   , employeeID: "' + $('#lstEmployeesMaster').val() + '"       }',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",

                        success: function (eventstring) {
                            var buildingEvents = $.map(eventstring.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    id: item.EventID,
                                    title: item.Title,
                                    start: item.StartDate,
                                    end: item.EndDate,
                                    allDay: false,
                                    //...(More Fields)
                                };
                            });

                            callback(buildingEvents);
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            //alert(data);
                        }
                    });
                },
               //...(Additional Functions for other events)
             ],
```

The webmethod is basically layed out like below. I have just removed some additional logic that doesn't relate to the question. You could probably skip the while loop and just use a list of (your class).ToArray() but I needed the while for additional functionality I have removed from this code.

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function LoadCalendarEvents(ByVal startDate As String, ByVal endDate As String, ByVal employeeID As String) As Array
    Dim events As DataSet

    If employeeID > 0 Then ' Individual Employee
        events = dbEvents.ListByEmployeeForNewCalendar(employeeID, startDate, endDate)
    Else ' Office
        events = dbEvents.ListByOfficeForNewCalendar(-1 * employeeID, startDate, endDate)
    End If

    Dim eventList As New ArrayList()

    Dim i As Int32 = 0
    While i < events.Tables(0).Rows.Count ' Load the details for each event in the range
        Dim startonDate As DateTime = CDate(events.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(14))
        Dim endonDate As DateTime = CDate(events.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(15))

        Dim eventRecord As New CalendarEventDetail ' This is a simple class with properties for the event detail
        eventRecord.StartDate = Format(startonDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        eventRecord.EndDate = Format(endonDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        eventRecord.EventID = events.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0).ToString()
        ' Additional stuff removed

        eventList.Add(eventRecord)

        i += 1
    End While

    Return eventList.ToArray
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the fullcalendar docs:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

From documentation:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    eventSources: [

        // your event source
        {
            url: '/myfeed.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                custom_param1: 'something',
                custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            },
            color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
            textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
        }

        // any other sources...

    ]

});
```